# Error With CiviCRM Volunteer

Tags: civivolunteer

I am getting the following error in CiviCRM:

M_Volunteer_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Permission.php on line 151

No idea why.

CiviCRM Version:  5.13.4
WP Version:  5.2.1
PHP Version:  7.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed now but the new version is still not available. You can either apply the patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/477.patch) or replace the extension by downloading from [here](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/archive/master.zip).

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Did you have any luck? To replace the extension, I used the joomla installer to install over top. Was that ok? I still have the error. Any recommendations?

Comment: I apologize I am in a WordPress setting. I simply reinstalled a snapshot from an earlier date and when I updated the fix later everything worked.